# mkfifo causes terminal to hang?

Tags: cygwin, mkfifo

Does `mkfifo` simply not work with Cygwin? A simple set of commands such as

```
$ mkfifo my_pipe

$ echo "1234" > my_pipe
```

just causes the terminal to sit forever with the cursor blinking. Am I "doing it wrong"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you're not doing anything wrong with *either* of those commands, it's just your expectations are a little off.

What you're missing is something at the *other end* of that pipe, reading that data. This apparent hanging happens in Linux as well, so it's not a CygWin problem (or any sort of problem, really).

Just open up another window and enter:

```
cat <my_pipe
```

and you'll see the data appear, followed by the original `echo` completing.

Comment: But what happens that one gets a blinking cursor here? Is it that the command is just not (yet) executed as one presses <ENTER>? If one adds `&` at the end of the `echo` command, the process is sent running in the background, waiting for the other end of the pipe to be read from, so this means that the command *is* executed. So is it then that the command does get executed but the resulting process stands in a special mode/status, and if so what is this status?

Comment: @TheQuark: it's more accurate to say that, once you hit ENTER, the command is *executing* rather than executed. There are three states here, not two: before running, running, and finished. The same thing happens with the command `sleep 60` - while the program is running, all you will see is that blinking cursor. The bottom line is that `echo` has not yet completed its task so will not exit.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with named pipes is that you need to have something on both ends. You can't write into a pipe if it isn't complete yet, so the `echo` command hangs until something else tries to read from that pipe, which in your case never happens.