# How to read from file descriptor in the background of shell script

Tags: bash, shell, file-descriptor

My problem is when I read from `/dev/fd/3` with `cat` the bash file will hang. I'm hoping for a way to read from the file descriptor in the background so I can continue on to the rest of the shell code.

```
#hangs here. pipe file descriptor 3 to yummy-stdin.pl
cat /dev/fd/3 | yummy-stdin.pl

./this-shall-never-run.pl
```

I've tried:

```
cat /dev/fd/3 | yummy-stdin.pl & this-shall-never-run.pl;
```

The problem with the above is while it's processing this-shall-never-run.pl, it will stop reading from the file descriptor. When it's finished, it will continue reading... but this isn't what I want.

Comment: if i use `cat /dev/fd/3 > my_pipe` won't it just hang there? I dont see that solving my problem

Comment: How do you attach a stream to cat's fd 3? You'd normally do that with `... 3< some-file` or inheriting it from the parent.

Comment: @StevenPenny This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12667621/mkfifo-causes-terminal-to-hang

Comment: @AustinAllover You are `cat`ing file descriptor 3, but what file does file descriptor 3 represent (in your shell)? Normally, if you haven't previously opened file descriptor 3 in your shell (with a command like `exec 3</some/file`) and your shell did not inherit file descriptor 3 from its parent (which it really shouldn'ty have) then it shouldn't even be a valid file descriptor. As such, I am surprised your command is hanging rather than giving an error. Anyway, [what is it that you're trying to do here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this form of bash redirection instead along with tagging it as a background task:

```
yummy-stdin.pl $(< /dev/fd/3) &
./this-shall-never-run.pl
```