# Using fifos and links to control remote process from a webpage (Linux)

Tags: linux, process, pipe, html, mkfifo

I'm using mpg123 in a linux server and I'm trying to control it through a webpage (apache), using links to send different controls.

mpg123 has the [-C](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpg123) flag so you can send characters to it. "s" key = start/stop, "f" key = next track... and so on.

I think I can send mpg123 those keys with a fifo, changing mpg123 stdin to the fifo stdout but i don't know how to use the fifo in this case (how to make mpg123 "listen" to another stdin).
What I've done is:

```
mkfifo myfifo
myfifo | mpg123 -C -@ musiclist.txt
And then I've created keys.txt adding some keys to the file:
echo "f" >> keys.txt
echo "s" >> keys.txt
```

Then:

```
cat keys.txt >> myfifo.fifo
```

This does not work.
Can someone explain ow can I use fifos to pass messages to a running mpg123?
I've googled it but can't find what I want.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667621/mkfifo-causes-terminal-to-hang/12667637#12667637) seems to give me some light, but I still don't know how to make mpg123 listen to the fifo's output.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: If you want to provide a web-interface to a command-line program then  you don't need mkfifo if it can accept input from stdin as in your case.

Comment: here's an example of how you could connect [a command-line program and web browser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11729467/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mpg123 has it's own --fifo option

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to pipe myfifo?

I'll assume `cat myfifo | mpg123 -C -@ musiclist.txt`

cat will close after the first file piped through myfifo.  Try using `tail -f myfifo | ...` instead to keep it open after EOF.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkfifo myfifo
tail -f myfifo | mpg123 .. &
# send commands
echo .. > myfifo
sleep 5
echo .. > myfifo
```

`tail` is optional unless `mpg123` exits if it receives EOF on stdin. Otherwise you could use: `<myfifo mpg123 ..`.

`&` at the end (control operator to execute the command in the background) is optional if you run `echo` commands in another terminal.